# Steps to remove transactional replication

Tags: sql-server-2012, transactional-replication

I'm looking for some good articles, documentations or links on how to completely remove SQL Server 2012 Transactional Replication?  I currently have three SQL Server machines that participate in transactional replication (let's say SQL-P, SQL-D and SQL-S).  The letter P stands for publisher, D distributor and S subscriber.  I'm looking for steps or sequence of steps that I need to perform to completely remove all components involved in this setup including dropping the distribution database.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to go about this, BUT the cleanest is to use SSMS. You will need to go to the publisher, expand the replication folder, right click on each publication, and delete the publication. That will prompt you to connect to the subscriber, and remove the subscription components there. If you use SSMS as described, then it will fire off the necessary scripts to remove the replication metadata on the publisher, subscriber, and distributor.

If you are unable to use SSMS to remove replication, you can also use stored procedures that can be run on the publisher and subscriber to clean all the replication components up. See link included below for the details on the stored procedures.

Once you have all publications removed, you can disable publishing and distribution via SSMS.

There are links to all the information you need on this page - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms152757(v=SQL.105).aspx . Please read carefully, and you should be fine.

If you run into issues, please let me know.

Comment: David, under what condition/scenario I might run into issues when using SSMS to remove replication?

Comment: I just re-read your reply.  It seems like the only machine that I need to connect to to perform the removal is SQL-P which is my publisher.  Is this correct?  At the end of deleting the publication, will the distribution db be removed automatically too?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. All this can be done from the publisher. Once you remove all the publications, you will need to follow the steps to disable publishing and distribution. At that point the distribution database will be cleaned up.